# How to find path of file outside the working directory dynamically?

Tags: python, path

I am working on an app where I have database file with history of computations and I need to access it so the user can see the data. But what if the user moves the database file? Then the app would not be able to find it, because the path would change. So how can I find the path, when the file can be anywhere in the computer.

Comment: is the database in the same relative place as the file ?

Comment: You would have no option other than to search the entire file system. Then you'd have the potential issue of 2 or more files existing with the same name

Comment: @PeterMoore yes, but only when I am testing the application, and I know that i cannot change the placement of the database. Problem is that I am 100% sure that someone will eventually move it and they would not be able to understand why the app is suddenly not working.

Comment: Since the "user" moved the file and the "user" uses the app then let the user tell you where it is after you alert the "user" path not found.

Answer (score 1):

the way to find a file on a Linux computer is to use the command `find` as in `find <path> -name <filename>`

python you can call that with

```
import subprocess    
run = subprocess.run(f'find {dirpath} -name {filename}', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
if run.returncode 
possible_paths = [p for p in run.stdout.splitlines() if "Permission denied" not in p]
```

the other more portable method if `find` is not on the computer, is using the `pathlib` module which you should learn if you have not encountered yet. Then you will create a find command like this that iterates though dirs to find a filename.

```
from pathlib import Path

def find(dirpath, filename):
    matches = []
    
    for p in dirpath.iterdir():
        try:
            if p.is_dir():
                matches.extend( find(p, filename) )
            elif p.name == filename:
                # is a file
                print(p)
                matches.append(p)
        except PermissionError as e:
            print(e)
            

    return matches

etc = Path('/etc/')

file = 'K90network'
print( find(etc, file) )
```

what you get back from that is the path objects to the file.

```
[PosixPath('/etc/rc.d/rc0.d/K90network'), PosixPath('/etc/rc.d/rc1.d/K90network'), PosixPath('/etc/rc.d/rc6.d/K90network'), PosixPath('/etc/rc0.d/K90network'), PosixPath('/etc/rc1.d/K90network'), PosixPath('/etc/rc6.d/K90network')]
```

Then you can just make that into list of strings or use that path to do operations on the file like opening it.

**Edit:**
Ive updated the function because although it would have worked for the `hosts` file, but it didn't handle permission denied properly and it didn't pass back results from deeper calls. So files like `K90network` were not being returned. But now it handles all that.

I also should point out that there is a member function [samefile()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.samefile) in these path objects that you can ask if they are the same file (if they are linked). `pathlib.Path` is one of the best additions to python in years IMO.